# Horizontal Scroll on Item Within Swipable Cards

Tags: java, android, swipe, horizontal-scrolling

I have added Swipable Cards in my current app, and I have to add horizontal scroll on gallary of images within particular card.

I want both left right swipe and horizontal scroll to work.

Kindly suggest

Comment: add xml, java and screenshots please

Comment: sorry cant share screenshot, Please swipable cards screenshot and within that I have added the views to horizontal scroll at run time.